# Dynamic Gnu Makefile rules using define, foreach and call

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to define a munch of rules like this:

```
x-9: y-9 z-9 x-8
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-9 --out-y=y-9 --in-x=x-8
x-8: y-8 z-8 x-7
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-8 --out-y=y-8 --in-x=x-7
x-7: y-7 z-7 x-6
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-7 --out-y=y-7 --in-x=x-6
x-6: y-6 z-6 x-5
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-6 --out-y=y-6 --in-x=x-5
x-5: y-5 z-5 x-4
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-5 --out-y=y-5 --in-x=x-4

x-4:
    touch x-4
```

As you can see, the basic idea is that I have a target

outputfile-NUMBER:

which has a couple of dependencies, either containing `NUMBER` in their name or containing `NUMBER-MINUS-ONE` in their name.

My goal would be that when I try to build the final target `x-9` it automatically `x-8`, `x-7`... down to `x-4`.

I tried something like

```
define oprule
x-$(1): x-$(1) y-$(1) z-$(1) x-$(2)
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-$(1) --out-y=y-$(1) --in-x=x-$(2)
endef

ttt = 9 8 7 6 5
$(foreach now, $(ttt), \
    $(call oprule, $(now), $(shell $$(( $(now)-1 )) ) ) )
```

I thought this would generate the 5 rules, but when I try

```
make x-9
```

I get the message

```
Makefile:93: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

and I don't know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
define oprule
x-$(1): y-$(1) z-$(1) x-$(2)
    python gen-files.py --out-x=x-$(1) --out-y=y-$(1) --in-x=x-$(2)

endef
```

The last newline preceding `endef` is always eaten out (just like the first newline following `define`). So you must have one more for `foreach` to generate the right line splitting (or add some sort of `$(nl)` macro after calling oprule).

P.S. And also do not put space after comma. Although it won't hurt in this particular case, but in general the spaces are significant for make.

Comment: Haha, yeah, right. The shell-eval was only for demonstrating. I actually do dates... `ttt = 201807 201806 201805 201804 201803 201802`, 
`$(foreach now, $(ttt), \ `, `$(call oprule, $(now), $(shell date +%Y%m --date="$$(date +$(now)01) -1 month") ) )`... so I need shell here. and that's actually not the problem. I think it's in my `oprule`...

Comment: @towi Ah, you mean you forgot the newline. Okay, I'll rewrite my answer.